# Python using a variable as your source code

Tags: python, python-requests

so I am trying to use the requests module to make an auto-updater for my program.
I want to take the text from a Pastebin file and use that as my code. This is what I've done so far.

```
import requests

coderaw = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/s3d1kWgu')

code = coderaw.text
```

So I want the "code" variable to be my source code.
Does anybody know a module or an operator that lets me do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of the implication of doing that?

Comment: This is a very bad idea; at least validate the code you download using a cryptographic signature or something. What you are currently trying to do would basically give full control of your computer (or your users' computers, if your program is used by anyone else) to whoever either gets your pastebin password or otherwise acquires the ability to edit what's at that pastebin link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use exec to execute the code in coderaw, for example:

```
my_code = 'print ("Hello World!")'
exec(my_code)
```

Using your code:

```
import requests
coderaw = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/s3d1kWgu')
code = coderaw.text
exec(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to take the risk then you can just [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) it.